# Synonym for "proud parents"

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a synonym for "proud parents" or "thrilled parents" (of a newborn child) but don't want to use *proud* as it looks bit show-offy.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use *proud*, you've already got your *thrilled* option.  But honestly, the phrase *proud parents*, when used to refer to parents of a newborn, is generally understood to mean *happy* parents.  They are beaming because they are overjoyed, not because they are proud, per se.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Delighted/well-pleased/joyous/elated/ecstatic parents

Comment: Delighted is very good, thanks. not enough rep yet

Answer (score 8):

"Recently reproduced?"
"Delighted dad" and "Merry mom"
"Excited ancestors?"  (not quite alliterative, but hey)
"Pleased progenitors?"
"Beaming begetters?"

Comment: I should have been clear - only looking for the "proud" or "thrilled" part

Comment: @romesub - In that case may I suggest: [http://thesaurus.com/browse/proud](http://thesaurus.com/browse/proud)

Comment: yes i did that, but could not find "delighted" which suits me perfectly from the other answer

Comment: @romesub - My point is that in your question you asked for a synonym for the *phrase* "proud parents".  If all you wanted was a synonym for a single word, then this is basically a thesaurus lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of being proud parents we are "Blessed parents" and also I've substituted "being a proud American to Blessed American.

Comment: That introduces a religious connotation of course, which is fine, but may not always be appropriate.