# Expression for parents who are "silly" happy?

Tags: word-choice

I was wondering if there is an expression to describe parents (usually newly-made) that are extremely happy with having children, with this happiness manifesting as "childish" behavior on their part when interacting with their offspring.

As an example consider someone with a 6-month-old baby that talks to the baby in a silly voice, makes cartoon faces and sounds, moves the baby around while simulating a train or aeroplane (with sound effects) and so on; at the same time *this person does not hesitate to do these things in front of others* -- possibly even complete strangers.

In Greek we call this person χαζομπαμπάς (father)/χαζομαμά (mother), a term that literally translates to "silly dad/mom" but does not carry negative connotations. At the very worst someone might call you that to imply that the parent is incapable of denying the child any request, but usually it simply means "this person is so happy that they don't pay any attention to appearances".

Is there something similar in English? I have already looked at [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31501/synonym-for-proud-parents), but it's not exactly what I 'm looking for because I read it as having to do with feelings, while I am specifically interested in how those feelings manifest as behavior.

Comment: I suggest we call them *newlybreds*.

Comment: As a native speaker of both Greek and English, I think that _doting_ is probably the best you will find. It does not have the same connotations as χαζομπαμπάς/μαμά but that is probably because there is no real translation of χαζοχαρούμενος/η into English and that is where I guess the words come from. However, doting does not really have _bad_ connotations. It brings to mind a parent who lives for their child.

Comment: Though this isn't a name for the parents that engage in this behavior, the behavior itself is called baby talk.

Comment: @KristinaLopez the word the OP is looking for encompases more than baby talk. It means that the parent in question is obsessed with their child but in a sweet way. No baby talk need be involved, rather the parent walks around with a stupid grin all day, can't stop talking about the child etc.

Comment: @terdon, that's why my contribution is a comment, not an answer.  I'm saying that the talking silly part, which the OP mentions specifically, is called "baby talk".  :-)

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps you are looking for [doting](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dote):-

> dote intr.v. dot·ed, dot·ing, dotes  To show excessive fondness or
>   love: parents who dote on their only child.
>   doter n.

Comment: I am aware of that word, but also under the impression that it has negative connotations (as in "suffocating love"). Is the impression correct? Contrast with what I 'm trying to describe above.

Comment: @Jon, perhaps, but any negativity would normally involve the doting parents appearing ridiculous or absurd, rather than being actively harmful.

Comment: There's also the somewhat more "clinical" term [permissive parents](http://psychology.about.com/od/childcare/f/permissive-parenting.htm) - characterised, as per that link, by the fact that they *often seem more like a friend, rather than a parent.*

Comment: Also *adoring* and *infatuated*

Comment: In Portuguese we have the expression 'pais babados' (drooling parents). The parents may appear ridiculous, but in a completely endearing way. It's more like pride for the child they brought into the world, but it doesn't imply the inability of saying 'no' to the child (so it doesn't equate with permissiveness, although it can also happen). Doting seems to transmit a similar idea but too formal and lacking the socially approved silliness factor. The same holds true for @jwpat7's two suggestions.

Comment: @SaraCosta the Greek term is pretty much exactly what you describe. It is the "socially approved silliness factor" that we're looking for.

Comment: "doting parents" of an infant carry a very positive connotation. To call the parents of a teenager, or even a child of elementary-school age, "doting" does have a negative connotation. And the connotation seems to get more negative the older the child gets.

Comment: When I hear _dote_, I don't necessarily think of baby talk, cooing, and vroom-vroom noises. Rather, I think of catering to, pampering, and indulging. We can dote without acting silly. It's not a bad suggestion to start the discussion, but I still think it misses the mark.

Comment: Interesting discussion! As terdon says, SaraCosta has the Portuguese equivalent nailed down. In the meantime I was slowly gravitating towards "doting" as the correct term, but J.R.'s comment above acted as a reset to my original position. Perhaps there is no exact word to describe *pais babados* after all...

Comment: @Jon: I don't know if there's a word for it. I might say, "Those parents are acting like Elmo," but I'm afraid that would carry a negative connotation – at least in my mind. :^)